# Is there a way to programmatically find the available CamelContext

Tags: apache-camel

I am running Camel inside PlayFramework and it all works pretty well but when the Play server is running in development mode it does dynamically class reloading but it starts a new Camel context each time.

I can hook into Play restart and shut down the Camel context by calling stop() on the CamelContext but I would prefer to be able to check if there is already a context running and if so just use that.

This must be possible as hawtio shows me a list of the camel contexts.

I don't use spring to configure camel.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JMX to see what other CamelContext's are in the JVM mbean server. This is what hawtio uses to detect which Camel's are running in the JVM.

As alternative you may fiddle with `Container` spi to have events when a `CamelContext` is created. But this requires a way to hook into this: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spi/Container.java